# how to use script in msearch request in Elasticsearch Java client 8

Tags: elasticsearch

my msearch request is like below:

```
{}
{ "query": { "bool": { "must": { "match_all": {} }, "filter": { "geo_distance": { "distance": "3km", "distance_type": "arc", "latLon": { "lat": 12.9322, "lon": 77.6904 } } } } }, "script_fields": { "distance_in_m": { "script": "doc['latLon'].arcDistance(40.00327, 15.36496)" } } }
{}
{ "query": { "bool": { "must": { "match_all": {} }, "filter": { "geo_distance": { "distance": "3km", "distance_type": "arc", "latLon": { "lat": 12.9322, "lon": 77.6904 } } } } }, "script_fields": { "distance_in_m": { "script": "doc['latLon'].arcDistance(40.00327, 15.36496)" } } }
```

How to write this in ElasticSearch java-client 8? In ElasticSearch java-client version 7 this is possible via https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/java-rest-high-multi-search.html but in version 8 not able to find how to add script_fields for each query separately.